# Input and select fields have different lengths

Tags: html, css

I have a form with different types of fields. Form's width is set to `100%`, so are its fields, but they have different lengths. Why do HTML form's input and select fields have different lengths and how to fix that? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/kw8u9gdz/2/

```css
.adapterSettings table {
 width: 100%;
}

.adapterInput select {
 width: 100%;
}
.adapterInput input {
 width: 100%;
}
.dvb-t2-s2 {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="dvb-t2-s2">
    <tr>
      <td>Frequency:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <select>
          <option value="S">DVB-S</option>
          <option value="T">DVB-T</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stream ID:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="number" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="submit" style="float: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with box sizing - whether it includes border, padding and margins in width or not. Your problem would be solved if you had set `border-box` in `box-sizing`:

```
.adapterInput * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add '`box-sizing: border-box;'` to this elements or just to all elements adding this to your css:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

**SNIPET**

```css
.adapterSettings table {
 width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.adapterInput select {
 width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.adapterInput input {
 width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dvb-t2-s2 {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="dvb-t2-s2">
    <tr>
      <td>Frequency:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <select>
          <option value="S">DVB-S</option>
          <option value="S2">DVB-S2</option>
          <option value="T">DVB-T</option>
          <option value="T2">DVB-T2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stream ID:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="number" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="submit" style="float: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

border-left + padding-left + content + border-right + padding-right =total-width

`select element` :

**1px + 0px + 993px + 1px + 0px = 995px;**

`number element`:

**2px + 0px + 995px + 2px + 0px = 999px;**

`submit element` :

**2px + 6px + 979px + 2px + 6px = 995px;**

so `number element` have 4px width more than other elements,here is `2 ways` for fix it :

**1)** Use of `box-sizing`:

insert this code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.adapterSettings table {
  width: 100%;
}

.adapterInput select {
  width: 100%;
}
.adapterInput input {
  width: 100%;
}
.dvb-t2-s2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="dvb-t2-s2">
    <tr>
      <td>Frequency:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <select>
          <option value="S">DVB-S</option>
          <option value="T">DVB-T</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stream ID:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="number" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="submit" style="float: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**2)** Use of `calc` :

```
.adapterInput input {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.adapterInput input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.adapterSettings table {
  width: 100%;
}

.adapterInput select {
  width: 100%;
}

.adapterInput input {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.adapterInput input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
}
.dvb-t2-s2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="dvb-t2-s2">
    <tr>
      <td>Frequency:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <select>
          <option value="S">DVB-S</option>
          <option value="T">DVB-T</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stream ID:</td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="number" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="adapterInput">
        <input type="submit" style="float: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```